# Linq2Entities query to find records given mix-max range

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have those two entities:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public int SeatId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ForDate { get; set; }

    public Seat Seat { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TicketStop> TicketStops { get; set; }
}

public class TicketStop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public int LineStopStationId { get; set; }

    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public LineStopStation LineStopStation { get; set; }
}

public class LineStopStation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public int StopId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastStop { get; set; }

    public Line Line { get; set; }
    public Stop Stop { get; set; }
}
```

The business case is that I am implementing a bus ticket reservation system (for learning purposes mostly) and I want to find overlapping tickets.

The combination of `LineId` + `ScheduleId` + `ForDate` identifies uniquely that that a ticket is for certain bus at a certain date and departure time.

The problem I have is to identify, given starting and end location whether or not two tickets overlap for one or more stops.

The `LineStopStation` entity holds information about the `StopId` and the `Order` in which it is visited during the bus trip. So basically, overlapping tickets will have same `Order` number at some point (unless it is the last stop, which means that the passenger is leaving the bus).

So what I have is `LineId`, `ScheduleId`, `StartId` and `EndId` where starId and endId correspond to `LineStopStation.StopId` so eventually I am able to get the Order out of them like this.

```
        int startStationOrder = _context.LineStopStations
            .First(l => l.LineId == lineId && l.StopId == startId).Order;

        int endStationOrder = _context.LineStopStations
            .First(l => l.LineId == lineId && l.StopId == endId).Order;
```

So I am pretty convinced that having all this information I should be able to find if in `TicketStop` table I have ticket which overlaps with the data in question. `TicketStop` works this way - if someone bought a ticket for 3 stops I will have three records there with the same `TicketId` and three different `LineStopStationId`.

I feel that this question got a bigger than needed. So basically I have this:

```
 public List<Seat> GetAvailableSeats(int lineId, int scheduleId, int startId, int endId, DateTime forDate)
 {
   int startStationOrder = _context.LineStopStations
       .First(l => l.LineId == lineId && l.StopId == startId).Order;

   int endStationOrder = _context.LineStopStations
       .First(l => l.LineId == lineId && l.StopId == endId).Order;

   var reservedSeats = _context.TicketStops
       .Where(t => t.Ticket.ScheduleId == scheduleId)
       .Where(t => t.Ticket.ForDate == forDate)
       //basically I don't know how to proceed here.
       //In pseudo code it should be something like:
       .Where(t => t.Min(Order) >= endStationOrder || t.Max(Order) <= startStationOrder

 }
```

But obs. this is not how `LINQ` works. So how can I find all tickets where this range overlaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an in-depth analysis of your model, perhaps something like this could give you an idea?

```
var reservedSeats = _context.TicketStops
                            .GroupBy(t => new { t.Ticket.ScheduleId, t.Ticket.ForDate })
                            .Where(tg => tg.Key == new { ScheduleId = scheduleId, ForDate = forDate })
                            .Where(tg => tg.Min(t => t.LineStopStation.Order) >= endStationOrder || tg.Max(t => t.LineStopStation.Order) <= startStationOrder);
```

You could also filter first and do an empty `GroupBy`:

```
var reservedSeats = _context.TicketStops
                            .Where(t => t.Ticket.ScheduleId == scheduleId && t.Ticket.ForDate == forDate)
                            .GroupBy(t => 1)
                            .Where(tg => tg.Min(t => t.LineStopStation.Order) >= endStationOrder || tg.Max(t => t.LineStopStation.Order) <= startStationOrder);
```

To return all the `SeatId`s, you just need to select them from the group.

```
var reservedSeats = _context.TicketStops
                            .Where(t => t.Ticket.ScheduleId == scheduleId && t.Ticket.ForDate == forDate)
                            .GroupBy(t => 1)
                            .Where(tg => tg.Min(t => t.LineStopStation.Order) >= endStationOrder || tg.Max(t => t.LineStopStation.Order) <= startStationOrder);
                            .SelectMany(tg => tg.Select(t => t.Ticket.SeatId));
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. It think I figure it out myself but if you have time, one more question. After the grouping and filtering I want to take the actual `SeatId`s which follow in these conditions. Is it correct to write: `.Select(tg => tg.First().Ticket.SeatId)` It seems to return the correct result but as you can see I'm not fluent with LINQ\GroupBy. Anyways, Thanks.

Comment: It appears you would have multiple tickets in the group `tg` - will all the `SeatId`s be the same, or do you need to make a decision on which to return? That will certainly work, but it is only returning the first match in a (possibly) random order.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. The `SeatId`s are different so getting just one is not sufficient, but the `GroupBy` approach is the way to go IMO. However since it's one of the most important parts in my implementation I've decided to include min/max Order in the `Ticket` Entity too, which denormalize the structure but makes it a lot more easier to use. So for now I won't put more effrort into that. If you are interested I will appreciate a solution with `GroupBy` where all `SeatId`s are returned.

Comment: @Leron That's easy  - you just need to select them from each group. I used `SelectMany` to undo the group, but you could also do a nested `Select` and then a `First()` afterwards. LINQ to Entities might be able to translate one versus the other.